# Node js unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm trying to run my project on centos 7 OS, i'm trying to install my project by writing node install_server.js 
and the terminal returns me an error

```
    install_server.js:26
fs.readFile(`${__dirname}/config/config.sql`, (err, data) => {
            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

And my source code of this file is found below

```
const cfg = require('./config/config.json');
const knex = require('knex');
const fs = require('fs');
const mysql = require('mysql');
var db = knex({
    client: 'mysql',
    pool: {
        min: 0,
        max: 1
    },
    connection: {
        host: cfg.database.db_server,
        user: cfg.database.db_user,
        password: cfg.database.db_password


    }
});
var myCon = mysql.createConnection({
    multipleStatements: true,
    host: cfg.database.db_server,
    user: cfg.database.db_user,
    password: cfg.database.db_password

});
fs.readFile(`${__dirname}/config/config.sql`, (err, data) => {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    myCon.query(data.toString(), function(err, results) {
        if (err)
            throw err;

        console.log('complete')

    });
});
```

Cant seem to figure it out, could i get a helphand?

Comment: What node.js version do you use? Template strings were added in node v4.0.0

Comment: `node -v` refers to v 0.10.30, that means i need to update?

Comment: Yes, the latest is v8.2.1

Comment: @alexmac i updated to v8, after reproducing this command, i get the error `
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '${__dirname}/config/config.sql'
` althought this directory/file exists.

Comment: The new bug is not related to this question, please create a new one and describe the problem there.

Comment: If I can make a suggestion about your approach; the easier way to do it is to have your query file just export an object with all your queries.  For example, `module.exports = { getAllThings : "SELECT * FROM things;" }`.  Then your calling code can just require it: `var queries = require('./config/config.sql');` and you can call it like `queries.getAllThings` when you need the sql string.

Answer (score 2):

Template Literals are not supported until version 4.8.4 according to

http://node.green/

which is a great resource.